# How to find where to place item in linearlayout with drag and drop?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout

I have a linearlayout filled with programmatically created views. I have implemented drag and drop code (shown below) so that if I touch down on the right side of any of the views, they start in drag mode. The drag mode itself works fine but the problem I am having is finding out where to place the view on release so that it falls in the expected place. Thanks for the help in advance!

Here is the onTouchMethod of the view(s):

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                if (Math.round(event.getX()) >= 720) {
                                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                                    v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and here is the onDragMethod that is also placed on the views:

```
view.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                            break;
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                            LinearLayout owner = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();
                            owner.removeView(view);
                            owner.addView(view, getNewViewPosition(fillView.indexOfChild(v), Math.round(v.getY()), Math.round(event.getY())));
                            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

finally here is the getNewViewPosition method:

```
public int getNewViewPosition(int currentPosition, int stationaryY, int floatingY) {
        Toast.makeText(this, stationaryY + " and then " + floatingY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (floatingY - stationaryY <= 15) {
            return currentPosition - 1;
        } else {
            return currentPosition + 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, since I knew that my views had a height of 52 I was able to formulate this code:

```
public int getNewViewPosition(int currentPosition, int stationaryY, int floatingY) {
        if (floatingY - stationaryY >= 13) {
            return currentPosition - 1;
        } else if (floatingY - stationaryY <= 39) {
            return currentPosition + 1;
        } else
            return currentPosition;
    }
```